# failing to save data in a text file

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to make a class that takes info from the GUI this saves it to a text file which I use as my "Database" but for some reason the PrintWriter object doesn't write the new data in the file. here's my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IO {

    File f = new File("DB.txt");
    PrintWriter write;
    Scanner input;
    String[][] data;
    String nameToSearch;

    // search constructor
    public IO(String name) {
        super();
        nameToSearch = name;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found please restart the program");
        }
        data = new String[linesCounter()][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < linesCounter(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = input.nextLine();
            data[i][1] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public IO(String name, String number) {
        try {
            write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        write.println(name);
        write.println(number);
    }

    int linesCounter() {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found please restart the program");
        }
        int counter = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            input.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }
        return counter / 2;
    }

    int contactFinder() {
        for (int i = 0; i < linesCounter(); i++)
            if (data[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(nameToSearch))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    String nameGetter() {
        return data[contactFinder()][0];
    }

    String numGetter() {
        return data[contactFinder()][1];
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be the file it's writing to isn't where you think it is. Print the `file.getAbsolutePath()` and see if it's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to close the printwriter after you have finished writing into the file using [printwriter.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29)

```
  try {
            write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
              write.println(name);
              write.println(number);
              write.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
 For your NoSuchElement Excepion, you should check if there is a nextline in the file before invoking Scanner.nextline() using [Scanner.hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < linesCounter(); i++) {
      if(input.hasNextLine()){
        data[i][0] = input.nextLine();
        data[i][3] = input.nextLine();
    }
   }
```

Comment: No, if it is newlined, and it is in this example.

Comment: No @CBredlow, close() will flush automatically.

Comment: Tools like FindBugs (http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) would have pointed out the problem.

Comment: Acctually after adding write.close(); the data is saved :) 
now the problem is that when I search for something in the file it throws this exception 
'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
 at IO.<init>(IO.java:27)
 at GUI$Buttonlistener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:49)
 '
and a lot more but I can't write it here

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the PrintWriter never got flushed.  You can do this manually with

```
write.flush();
```

That will ensure the buffer gets written to the file.

Comment: the error was that I forgot to close the printwriter :) thanks anyway :)

Comment: I see, so closing must also flush.  Good to know.